# Root motion causes unwanted movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, mixamo

Why when I use Root Motion my character X position is slowly increasing and Y position is slowly decreasing when I am just moving forward? It is happening when I am tapping the button to move forward and not holding it.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADFFA.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cml6Q.png)

Answer (score 0):

The idea of root motion is that the the animation of the clip will have affect the motion (movement in this case) of the transform that is holding the Animator + mesh.

So if you have an animation clip that is moving forward, e.g. avatar_move_forward_clip , and for some reason you entered this state in your animator by pressing left or right, you will end up moving diagonally.

If you want a more detail diagnostic, you need to provide with more informations.

1. your movement + animator control code
2. your Animator setup.
3. your animation clip setup

And also I'm a bit confuse if we are talking 3D or 2D. Cuz in 3D, you move in XZ plane, and 2D move in XY plane. And I believe only 3D  will use root motion.

**Other Resources: About Root Motion**

"The primary benefit of root motion is your character follows the movement curve of the animation. This means if your animation has variable movement speed, the character SHOULD adjust their speed accordingly. This allows the animator to have full control of the movement speed" [Quote from a response [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/174362/reasons-to-not-use-root-motion#:%7E:text=The%20primary%20benefit%20of%20root,control%20of%20the%20movement%20speed.) ]